# Add content from PDF by scaling it and preserve its interactivity using iText

Tags: java, pdf, itext

I want to add a page from a pdf, pdf1 to another pdf, pdf2 at an absolute position by scaling the size of the page.
I know that this can be achieved by using PDFWriter/PDFStamper but the problem is that 
the pdf that i want to add (pdf1) has some interactivity and it should be preserved. 
I am aware that i have to use PDFCopy in order to preserve the interactive features of the PDF, but i can only add it in its original form and size. Is there a way this can be done?

Comment: How about using PdfCopy and in a second pass manipulating the mediabox and the user unit of the page?

Comment: mkl, thanks for that info, i'll try that out.

Comment: Concerning the user unit have a look at the specification [ISO 32000-1](http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf) section 7.7.3.3, table 30, entry **UserUnit**.

Comment: In the second pass, should i be using a stamper to modify the mediabox and userunit? can you point me to any example where i can find something like this?